# Assigning an unique identification variable across repeated values

Tags: r, unique, uniqueidentifier

I will create a simple example of some dummy data:

```
case <- c('a','a','a','b','b','c','c','c','c','d','d','e','e')
object <- c(1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2,3,1,1,1,2)

df1 <- data.frame(case, object)
```

Now for each unique `case` and `object` value, I want to create a corresponding unique numerical value (an identifier)

```
df1$UNIQ_ID <- ........
```

The end result should take the following values `c(1,1,2,3,3,4,4,5,6,7,7,8,9)` as when

```
unique(df1$object[df1$case=='a'])
unique(df1$object[df1$case=='b'])
```

I have though of using `dpylr` and `group_by(case)`

Comment: Another base R approach would be: `match(x <- interaction(df1$case, df1$object), unique(x))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the `.GRP` from `data.table` after grouping by 'case' and 'object' on a data.table object (`setDT(df1)`).

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[,UNIQ_ID:= .GRP ,.(case, object)]
df1
#     case object UNIQ_ID
# 1:    a      1       1
# 2:    a      1       1
# 3:    a      2       2
# 4:    b      1       3
# 5:    b      1       3
# 6:    c      1       4
# 7:    c      1       4
# 8:    c      2       5
# 9:    c      3       6
#10:    d      1       7
#11:    d      1       7
#12:    e      1       8
#13:    e      2       9
```

---

A `base R` option would be

```
grp <- interaction(df1)
as.numeric(factor(grp, levels= unique(grp)))
#[1] 1 1 2 3 3 4 4 5 6 7 7 8 9
```

Comment: Very simple thankyou. When we then give `str(df1)` we see that the class has changed "`Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame`"

Comment: does a `data.table` format have different behaviour to a `data.frame`

Comment: @user08041991  If you need to change it to `data.frame`, just use `setDF(df1)`

Comment: @user08041991  You can use the `data.table` methods for the `data.table` object (which would be faster)